# Postgresql jsonb column joins across two table first one is object and second one is array of objects

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I'm trying to do following thing,I lost some days working on this...
I think following code snippets are enough in order to understand the issue, if not please ask me.

```
table1
id second_table_id jsonb_field_name1    
1         2       "{"1": "value of text field", "2": [2, 3,4]}"
--------------- 
table2
id jsonb_field_name2 
2   "[{"id": 1, "name": "text field name", "type": "string"},{"id": 
    2, "name": "list field name", "type": "enum", "options": 
    [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3] {"id": 4]}]"
```

my query parameters are following:

```
1. field_name = "text field name" and type = "string" and value = 
"value of text field"
AND
2. field_name = "list field name" and type = "enum" and value in 
(4,3)
```

result have to be table1's record with id =1

My last version of select is following, but there is not query for/in options

```
select ar.id from table1 t1, table2 t2, 
jsonb_array_elements(t2.jsonb_field_name2) obj ,  
jsonb_each(t1.jsonb_field_name1) cf  where t2.id = 
t1.second_table_id   
and obj->>'name' ='text field name' and obj->>'type' ='string' and 
cf.key = obj->>'id' and cf.value::text = 'value of text field'
```

Comment: eh.. mu last hope was Stachoverflow but..

Comment: It is a bit confusing to follow what you exactly need based on the query you tried and the part of `my query parameters`. What does the `value` exactly mean in 1 & 2 parameters? And what do you mean by `there is not query for/in options` – what do you need to match there? But what it seems is that you may want to look into LATERAL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) in order to reference in same query level other results like you do in json functions there.